# What is the correct way to detect when JComboBox has <enter> key pressed and no dropdown exists?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox, keypress

We have a JComboBox element.

When you type something, it shows a dropdown of matching list elements.

When you press enter when one list element is selected, it will call an `ActionListener()`.

**How do I detect when an "Enter" key is hit when the combo box is already populated with the text (e.g. there's no active dropdown)?**

My best guess is that I need to get the ComboBoxEditor via getEditor(), and attach an event listener to that?

I can probably get a component of that ComboBoxEditor via `getEditorComponent()` and then do addKeyListener() on the component?

Comment: With a JSpinner I have done basically that. Obtained the editor and attached an ActionListener to that.

Comment: ListSelectionListener to derived JList

Comment: it shows a dropdown of matching list elements. == Document Events in Editor

Comment: why? typically, there is nothing to do if there is no change